# Meaning of the bound of the form `throws α` during Type Inference in Java

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, jls

According to JLS (§18.1.3)**"Bounds"** : it specifies regarding the inference of `throws α`:

> A bound of the form throws α is purely informational: it directs resolution to optimize the instantiation of α so that, if possible, it is not a checked exception type.

- this tells that `α` must be Optimized to be Instantiated as an **Unchecked Exception Type**.

But in the JLS (§18.1.2) **"Constraint Formulas"** : from which the bounds will be inferred as subsequent step:

> ‹LambdaExpression →throws T›: The checked exceptions thrown by the body of the LambdaExpression are declared by the throws clause of the function type derived from T.

- this tells that `α` represents an Instantiation of a **Checked Exception Type**.

Regarding the **Instantiations of α** there are **2 conflicting thoughts being presented. Am I missing something here?**